# python converting special characters to escaped characters

Tags: python, mysql

In my MySQL DB I have fields with special characters in, like a umlaut, there are probably others, I just picked this one up. When I do the search python changes it to an escape character "\xf6". If I search and export the same data via phpmyadmin it keeps umlaut, this is what I would python to do - Keep the special characters and not escape them. How can I achieve this ?

The collation of the table I am working with is utf8_bin

Example:
Wöll becomes W\xf6ll

Comment: You are confusing Python string *representations* with the actual value; `\xf6` is the ASCII-safe escape code for `ö`. This is the result of `repr(value)`, and can be used for debugging. *Your values are fine*.

Comment: You can `print 'W\xf6ll'` and it will display `Wöll`.

Comment: Please be more specific on _how you diagnose_ your problem.  Probably your way to diagnose is flawed and you see problems where in fact none are or vice versa (aka "ghosts").  For instance, tell us what you type and what you observe when you say that "python changes it to an escape character".  Be precise about the commands you type (and where, in an interactive console maybe?) and about the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use encoding and decoding when working with Unicode/UTF8 strings. Find more information and examples here:

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Also, here is a great article explaining the basics of string encoding and character sets:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, the author clearly did not reasearch before asking a question and these links are useful to understand the topic at hand.

Comment: I didn't downvote __but__ your answer is probably not well-suited to solve the issue at hand, even if, by the letters, you are technically right with your estimation.  So this answer makes this question _answered_ and thus much less attractive for other helpers.  That's why a very short and fast answer as the first one is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I understand and welcome your explanation, but I don't feel there is much more to help or answer when you take into account the sloppy manner in which the question is asked. Anything further than this broad answer would require many assumptions as to the nature of authors issues. He gave no specifics, so the answer can not contain any specifics. Correct me if I am wrong here please.

Comment: That's why I think this question should only get comments yet, until it gets clarified by the OP.

Comment: Ah I see your point, I should have commented instead of reply :) Well, im new to SO concepts :) Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence, I did not understand the issue fully until I read the links you supplied. That is why my post was perceived as vague and why I could not find much information on the net - Can't search for something if you don't really understand the issue. Thanks again.